# ModelViewSet - Selectively hide fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an `Instructor` model, which has a many to many field to a `Client` model. (`Instructor.clients`)

The model:

```
  class InstructorProfile(models.Model):
    '''Instructor specific profile attributes
    '''
    # Fields
    office_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    # Relationship Fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name="instructor_profile",
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    clients = models.ManyToManyField('ClientProfile', blank=True)
```

My serializer is currently:

```
class InstructorProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.InstructorProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

And viewset:

```
class InstructorProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ViewSet for the InstructorProfile class"""

    queryset = models.InstructorProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.InstructorProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

I'd like to prevent access to the `clients` field to everyone except the user which `Instructor` belongs to (available in the `Instructor.user` model field).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please show the model class?

Comment: added the instructor model

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `InstructorProfileViewSet`:

```
...
def get_queryset(self):
    if hasattr(self.request.user, 'instructor_profile'):
        return models.InstructorProfile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    else:
        return models.InstructorProfile.objects.none()
```

... if I guessed your InstructorProfile model correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be a reverse foreign key lookup? user is actually found in the InstructorProfile class. Change 'instructor' to 'instructor_profile' (the related name).

Comment: Yup yup. Correct.

Comment: See edited comment again please - "instructor_profile" as @jramm has inserted a related name.

Comment: Yeah just saw it too :)

Comment: I think this is about something else. You won't return the InstructorProfiles but the question is about how to not show only the client field. So all profiles has to be returned but some will have client:null or the field will missing from the response.

Comment: It will return nothing for non Instructors. Otherwise if you remove the field it introduces inconsistency. You can make it though overloading `__init__` of the Serializer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to change the list method to set the `client=None` where needed. This way you would preserve the response structure. It would be something like this:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    for i in serializer.data:
      if i['user'] != request.user.pk:
         i['client'] = None

    return Response(serializer.data)
```